# Angular CLI AOT build error

Tags: angular-cli

I am getting this error while building my angular-cli project. This error is coming for a 3rd party library angular-split. I googled this error and realized that it's coming because this library is not AOT compliant. I turned off the AOT and tried running the build but no luck. How can I fix this? I would also love to know opinion about using angular-cli in production.

```
Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, 
resolving symbol NgModule in /node_modules/angular-split/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module.d.ts, 
resolving symbol NgModule in /node_modules/angular-split/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata.d.ts, 
resolving symbol NgModule in /node_modules/angular-split/node_modules/@angular/core/src/core.d.ts, 
resolving symbol NgModule in /node_modules/angular-split/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts, 
resolving symbol AngularSplitModule in /node_modules/angular-split/dist/angularSplit.module.d.ts, 
resolving symbol AngularSplitModule in 
/node_modules/angular-split/dist/angularSplit.module.d.ts[39m[22m
```

Comment: You turned off the AOT and tried running the build? Exactly how did you do this? All you need to do is run `ng build --prod --aot false` to do a build without AOT.

Comment: @R. Richards - I tried your command and multiple other versions of turning off AOT. Nothing works! I also read few posts where people posted that they are still getting this error even after turning off AOT.

Comment: Odd, usually turning AOT off just does it's thing and works. Have you looked for any related issues on the library's GitHub? Maybe someone there has a work around. Good luck!

Comment: yes. Everyone is saying Turn off AOT or upgrade your libraries to be AOT Compliant. :) I will update here if I find a solution to this issue.